# php mysql query returns true even when empty set

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that takes a value(id) from the user using html form and looks for it in the database called "account" to display all values. If the value entered by the user doesn't exist in the database, it should display an alert.

```
//user_form.html

    <html>
    <form method="get" action="user_action.php">
    <input type="text" name="val"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
    </form>
    </html>

//user_action.php
<?php
    $name=$_GET["val"];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","my_username","my_password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("account",$con);
    if( ($result=mysql_query("select * from my_table where id=$name")) )
        //display the database table
    else
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Id not found in database!");</script>';
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is when I enter a value for id that doesn't exist in the database, it doesn't enter the else block and display the alert.
So, why is the query returning true for all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` will return true if the query is successful, even if no results are returned. You want to use [`mysql_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) to check if any rows are returned.

Also, you should really start using PDO or mysqli for your database queries. It's a lot more secure is not not deprecated unlike mysql_ functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

```
<?php
    $name=$_GET["val"];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","my_username","my_password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("account",$con);
    if( ($result=mysql_query("select * from my_table where id=$name")) ) {
       if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
         // Rows Returned
       }else{
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Id not found in database!");</script>';
       }
    } else {
      // Mysql Error (Error with Query)   
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query()
>   returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

To check if there are rows returned you need to use

```
mysql_num_rows()
```

More over you are using deprecated mysql_ function.

You should start `mysqli_ or PDO` with prepared statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( ($result=mysql_query("select * from my_table where id=$name")) )
```

It should be

```
if( ($result==mysql_query("select * from my_table where id=$name")) )
```

Comment: Because of the double parenthesis, the way he was doing it is correct to check if mysql_query was true of false. Double equal signs are not required since he is setting the result variable.

Comment: Even without the doubleparenthesis it's valid.  The single equals variant assigns the return value of `mysql_query` into $result and returns it again - so you are assigning the result to $result and simultaneously testing if $result is "true". == is comparing the return value from `mysql_query`to the value of `$result` - which since I doubt $result is defined yet is likely to be the oposite of what is wanted.